Can doping significantly decrease a monolayer semiconductor's band gap to almost metallic levels?
I am currently an undergraduate student tackling DFT calculations on my 3x3 CsGeBr3 perovskite monolayer with Fe-doping and Biaxial Straining using Quantum Espresso thru BURAI. I have found out that after calculating the band structure of my monolayer sample with 11% Fe-doping, the band gap decreased all the way down from 1.7 eV from the pristine form to 0.22 eV in the doped version. My adviser and one of my panelists have already remarked at how extremely significant (and perhaps unrealistic) the change was even at the lowest doping level. Is it possible for a monolayer
material like my sample to go drastic changes in its band gap thru doping or are there some unnoticed errors in my calculation? Below are the pictures of the band structure of my material from its pristine form to its doped form.



No, they are commenting that you are totally misunderstanding what the output of your simulation is trying to tell you. Your valence band seems fine, but your conduction band seems to be destroyed by the doping. You might want to scrutinise that. And brush up on the theoretical underpinnings of DFT.

@naturallyInconsistent can you provide some helpful insights/tips regarding the apparent peculiarities in the conduction band from the band structure?

Sorry, I do not know what happened to your conduction band. You might want to use a bigger supercell and see if the conduction band can return to its rightful position.
